# Android PreferenceActivity : Bundle is null in onCreate method after the onSaveInstanceState

Tags: java, android, preferenceactivity

I'm using the PreferenceActivity and want to restore its state while the device rotation.

I want to save the state onSaveInstanceState method:

```
 @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle icicle) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(icicle);

      icicle.putString("LevelsValue", levelPref.getSummary().toString());

    }
```

And in the onCreate method :

```
if (savedInstanceState!=null) 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "savedInstanceState is not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "savedInstanceState is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And I'm always getting the `savedInstanceState is null` message.

I know that I can use the `onStop` and `onResume` methods, but I think that is not the right approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by onResume and onStop methods using